# How can I create a usage pie chart in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat

I want to make a pie chart in android like this:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/Uh9eoU3.png]

Please help me out.

Comment: the image link is broken

Comment: Are you talking a out a pie chart with data provided by your app or a pie chart showing the different app usage as shown in the example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MPAndroidChart!

[Github link here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

Comment: Please do post answers that mainly consist of a link. In this case you should add a code example that creates a diagram similar to the one shown in the question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).